# Why is my action result giving me a 404?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I have this controller:

```
public class ActivityController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Activity
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ProfessionalActivityForm()
        {
            return View(new Activity());
        }
        public ActionResult TradeShow()
        {
            return PartialView("_AddTradeShow");
        }
        public ActionResult InsertTradeShow(TradeShow TradeShow)
        {
            TradeShow.Insert(TradeShow);
            return Content("Trade Show submitted successfully");
        }
        public ActionResult Conference()
        {
            return PartialView("_AddConference");
        }
        public ActionResult InsertConference(Conference Conference)
        {
            Conference.Insert(Conference);
            return Content("Conference submitted successfully");
        }
    }
```

when I do a `GET` for `/Activity/Conference`  I get my partial view returned to me just fine. However when I `GET` `/Activity/TradeShow` I get a 404. Then, if I switch the code in this controller so that Conference appears before TradeShow, then I get the opposite results - a 404 for Conference and a working partial view for TradeShow.

Why is this? Seems like I am missing something fundamental here...

Here is the jQuery I am using for ajax:

```
$('#ConferenceButton').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Activity/Conference',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#partialViewContainer').html(data);
                $('.focusMe').focus();
                //var top = $('.focusMe').offset().top;
                //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: top }, 700);
            }
        });
    });
    $('#TradeShowButton').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Activity/TradeShow',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#partialViewContainer').html(data);
                $('.focusMe').focus();
                //var top = $('.focusMe').offset().top;
                //$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: top }, 700);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: try to specify `dataType = "html"` in you `$.ajax` could be that default Intelligent Guess can gess what's comming from controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace `url` in `$.ajax({` to

```
 url: '@Url.Action("Conference", "Activity")',
```

and

```
url: '@Url.Action("TradeShow", "Activity")',
```

Also if your `ConferenceButton` and `TradeShowButton` use ActionLinks in the View like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Conference Button", "Conference", "Activity", null, new { id = "ConferenceButton" })
```

then you could use in the `url` this code:

```
 url: this.href,
```